# Why there is no the full history of jobs in the CronJob controller on the GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

[image: t s]

I have CronJob which run at least a few time. However, I cannot see the full history of this CronJob, although I set successfulJobsHistoryLimit to 10. Why?

Answer (score 0):

There is a history `Kubernetes Engine -> Workloads` and click the CronJob name.

[image]

If you cannot see it that might indicate your Job was scheduled just once.

Of course you can also check using `kubectl` command

```
$ kubectl get cj
NAME    SCHEDULE    SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
hello   * * * * *   False     1        7s              4m7s


$ kubectl get jobs
NAME               COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
hello-1563535260   1/1           2s         2m16s
hello-1563535320   1/1           1s         76s
hello-1563535380   1/1           1s         15s
```